# Flash Media Live Encoder

Tags: video-streaming, webcam, audio-streaming, video-encoding, flashmedialiveencoder

I am using Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder to stream live video to a video streaming server.

The webcam is in our office pointed out the window.

Thankfully, Flash Media Live Encoder has a checkbox to un-include audio.

I am wondering how I can push a recorded message to the audio ( or music ).  Is there any way I can play a recording and have it behave like a microphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

You can feed audio through your soundcard and select your soundcard inside flash media live encoder.

The answer lies in your ability to control your audio drivers. I have had it stream whatever is coming out my speakers before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can use and virtual audio streaming software, first link in Google:
http://www.virtualaudiostreaming.net/

This enables you to select music from your PC and "virtually play" it on your audio card.
Then from FMLE, just use that input as Audio signal.